# Muting my microphone causes my screen to go dark - why?

Tags: pulseaudio, brightness, microphone

I was having issues with my laptop's onboard microphone recently, so I decided to try muting and unmuting it. To my surprise, muting it caused my laptop's screen to go dark, and this would not respond to anything (including `xbacklight`).

The microphone is still not picking up anything I say. I know that it *is* functional, as it still picks up background noise if turned up high enough, but for some reason, it can't hear my voice.

I am using PulseAudio, and am on Parabola GNU/Linux-libre (an Arch fork). I would appreciate any suggestions of what could be the cause of this and how I can go about fixing it.

Edit: This is the contents of my /proc/asound/cards:

```
 0 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel HDMI
                  HDA Intel HDMI at 0xf7a14000 irq 46
 1 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                  HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7a10000 irq 42
```

Edit 2: I was asked by someone else to use a script which gave the following info: [info](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=ddda4e7e56f6f80429f8f1302a1b9c61b8a2e006).

Comment: This really depends on your hardware, so you need to include more information.  Also, how did you mute the microphone (hotkey, pavucontrol, alsamixer)?  What's in /proc/asound/cards, and what do you see in the output of `amixer -c <card> scontents`?

Comment: @user3188445 What information should I include? I muted via pavucontrol. I've added the contents of /proc/asound/cards to the original post.

Comment: And which sound card is causing the problem, the PCH?  If you run "alsamixer -c PCH" and TAB to the capture settings, is everything unmuted and with a reasonable volume?  This sounds like a driver (or maybe hardware) bug, so you'd really need to say what the hardware is and exactly what triggers the problem.  Ideally you could boil it down to some amixer command that 100% reproduces the problem and then report it upstream (but also need to know what video driver--presumably intel?)

Comment: have you tried muting using alsamixer instead? press the "m" key on the desired channel to toggle mute.

Comment: @user3188445 I've added even more information - this should help answer your question. Yes, it's the PCH, and with the capture settings, I literally *cannot* unmute 'Internal Microphone'.

Comment: @mchid Yeah, same deal.